# Angular call method based on 2 different observables

Tags: angular, typescript

I am extremely new to Angular (6 months), and am struggling with an issue.  I have two observables that currently operate separately:

```
this.siteService.siteChanged$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.disconnect$))
  .subscribe(_ => this.getGroups());

this.uiService.currentTab$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.disconnect$))
  .subscribe(tab => {
    if (tab != Tab.Groups) {
      this.windowService.pushToHistory({ group: this.groupService.selectedGroup?.groupId }, true);
    }
    else {
      this.totalCountChange.emit(this.allGroups.length);
      this.filteredCountChange.emit(this.filteredGroups.length);
    }
  });
```

My problem is that I really only need to call the method in the first one ("`this.getGroups()`") if the "tab" returned in the second is equal to "`Tab.Groups`", but I can't figure out how to combine them.  I tried using "forkJoin" but I could not figure out how to get the return of "tab" when the first one returns void, and it throws errors:

```
forkJoin(
  [this.siteService.siteChanged$,
  this.uiService.currentTab$]
).subscribe([void,tab] => {
  if(tab == Tab.Groups){
    this.getGroups();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did the following which seems to be working, but PLEASE, if there is a better or more proper way to do this please add an answer.

```
  this.siteService.siteChanged$.pipe(takeUntil(this.disconnect$)).subscribe(() => {
  this.uiService.currentTab$.pipe(takeUntil(this.disconnect$)).subscribe(tab => {
    if (tab == Tab.Groups) {
      this.getGroups();
      this.totalCountChange.emit(this.allGroups.length);
      this.filteredCountChange.emit(this.filteredGroups.length);
    }
    else {
      this.windowService.pushToHistory({ group: this.groupService.selectedGroup?.groupId }, true);
    }
  })
});
```